# npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v7.2.0

Tags: node.js, npm

npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v7.2.0, and I tried to type"npm uninstall -g npm", but it doesn't work, how could I do to fix it, thank you><

---

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v7.2.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
andyhuangde-MacBook-Air:~ andyhuang$ npm uninstall -g npm
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v7.2.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! path /private/tmp/npm.37658/package/npm-6.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/private/tmp/npm.37658/package/npm-6.4.1.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: What is your `npm` and `node` version?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install LTS version 10.15.3

And secondly why do you uninstall npm using

```
npm uninstall -g npm
```

If you uninstall npm how can you install node package ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your `npm` and `Node.js` version do not match the version.

Node.js 7.2 should use npm 3.10 (you can check the version  in [Previous Releases](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/))

You should change `npm` or `Node.js` to match version.

My recommend is use:
 - [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for Mac/Linux
 - [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) for window

It will auto download Node.js and npm match version(actually don't need this, when you download installer, it will auto user npm match version), easy to change update Node.js